# How to configure instant messaging in freepbx 14 & Asterisk 13

Tags: asterisk, sip, sms, freepbx

i have a trouble to configure instant messaging using freepbx 14 and asterisk 13 , i want that two sip clients can send and receive messages using their soft phones on smartphone and desktop , can anyone help me !

Comment: You're asking us to solve the entire problem, but you haven't given us much information, and you've not tried anything yourself (or, at least, you haven't told us what you've tried). You need to start by doing research, then try things yourself, and once you're on your way and come upon a problem you cannot research your way around you come here and ask.

Answer (score 0):

sip.config in GUI

accept_outofcall_message=yes
outofcall_message_context=astsms

### auth_message_requests=no

config file editor in GUI file extensions_custom.conf

[astsms]

exten => 1XX,1,NoOp(SMS receiving dialplan invoked)
exten => 1XX,n,NoOp(To ${MESSAGE(to)})
exten => 1XX,n,NoOp(From ${MESSAGE(from)})
exten => 1XX,n,NoOp(Body ${MESSAGE(body)})
exten => 1XX,n,Set(ACTUALTO=${CUT(MESSAGE(to),@,1)})
exten => 1XX,n,MessageSend(${ACTUALTO},${MESSAGE(from)})
exten => 1XX,n,NoOp(Send status is ${MESSAGE_SEND_STATUS})
exten => 1XX,n,GotoIf($["${MESSAGE_SEND_STATUS}" != "SUCCESS"]?sendfailedmsg)
exten => 1XX,n,Hangup()
;
; Handle failed messaging
exten => 1XX,n(sendfailedmsg),Set(MESSAGE(body)="[${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%d%m%Y-%H:%M:%S)}] Your message to ${EXTEN} has failed. Retry later.")
exten => 1XX,n,Set(ME_1=${CUT(MESSAGE(from),<,2)})
exten => 1XX,n,Set(ACTUALFROM=${CUT(ME_1,@,1)})
exten => 1XX,n,MessageSend(${ACTUALFROM},ServiceCenter)
exten => 1XX,n,Hangup()
exten => 1XX,n,Hangup()